# How to keep track of changes to configuration files for development and production environment

Tags: git, version-control, jboss, automation, system

I am developing an application that use JBoss, PostgreSQL, etc...

JBoss requires a lot of different configuration such as data sources, email servers, security etc.
How should I handle these configurations? Should the whole JBoss be put under a VCS?

Or is this just a thing that you will have to configure for each production server that you have, and then use some virtualization images for development?

Answer (score 0):

Well, storing whole JBoss in VCS is not an option at all. It is mostly binary thing and the size of configs is much smaller then size of JARs. Those JARs will never change. **DO NOT** put JBoss (or any other binary distro) in VCS.

I see a couple of ways to solve the problem.

First, you can store only configs you need in Git. That's the most basic, and not very flexible solution. You can, for example do symlinks on the git repo's configs on real server, but it is only available when the server has those repos fetched. On my practice I've never seen such server layout.

Or you can store the configs in git and have a tool which updates them on real environments. Once, in my practice, we have such set of Perl-based scripts. It's very simple and you have full control, but not non-standardized. It's kind of inventing a bicycle.

As you mentioned in you question, you can use VM images to achieve this thing. That's good if you have infrequent updates, as reinstalling the whole VM may be painful each time you update config. Also, thik about how you'd update those images? Can your CI server make an image? That's very tricky, imho.

The direction personally I would dig is using tools like [chef](https://www.getchef.com/chef/), [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home). It's very similar to VM image approach, but instead you install a client on every machine which "listens" to updates of configs and take required actions. Plus, it's a well-known tools, with big community, so finding help or support is easy. Anyway, you can find it useful to store sample configs right in the main codebase for the developers who want use them on their own machine without those tools installed.

Comment: Okey, I understand. I have looked at those tools and also Docker. I guess I am on the right track then by checking out those tools. It seems Docker is an alternative too?

Comment: Docker is great as it can really easylly pack all your app and dependencies in independent container on a build stage. All you need to do after is to `docker pull` the latest image and `docker run` it! However, even if Docker is super-lightweight compared to VM, it can be an overkill to pack simple apps in containers.